# Is there any way to sort values of this table in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have two table one is for chats and other for users and i have some user_id. i need to sort the user id using last message send by two id.

**`User table:`**

| id | name | email | password |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | xyz | xyz@g | 123 |
| 5 | abc | abc@g | 123 |
| 7 | pqr | pqr@g | 123 |
| 4 | lmn | lmn@g | 123 |

**`Chat table:`**

| id | sender | receiver | message | timeline |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 102 | 6 | 5 | 123 | 2021-10-16 03:09:08 |
| 103 | 6 | 7 | 123 | 2021-11-17 05:20:28 |
| 110 | 6 | 5 | 123 | 2021-12-16 06:19:20 |
| 112 | 6 | 4 | 123 | 2021-10-18 11:29:08 |

I need to sort the user table using the highest id in chat table.
for example here 112 is highest chat id and its receiver id is 4 the i need to sort my user table like

4 and then 5 which has chat_id 110 and then 7 which has 103

so user table need to look like:

| id | name | email | password |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | lmn | lmn@g | 123 |
| 5 | abc | abc@g | 123 |
| 7 | pqr | pqr@g | 123 |

6 is not there so no need of adding in the resulted table

i did'nt mean to update the table. i mean to select those values from table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `GROUP By` and `MAX` aggregation to find applicable chat id for each user.

```
SELECT a.*
FROM users a 
JOIN (
    SELECT receiver, MAX(id) AS id
    FROM chat 
    GROUP BY receiver
) c ON a.id = c.receiver
ORDER BY c.id DESC
```

OR

```
SELECT a.id, MAX(a.name) AS name, MAX(a.email) AS email, MAX(a.password) AS password
FROM users a 
JOIN chat c ON a.id = c.receiver
GROUP BY a.id
ORDER BY MAX(c.id) DESC
```

Comment: sorry its not working! your query grouping users with least chat id. i need to group user with highest chat id order.

Comment: MAX() is getting the highest, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b318e2f/3

Comment: yesssss!!  its working thanks a lot for taking your time to help. thank you